# How to find a node by id in the PrimeNg tree?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-tree-component, primeng-tree

We are moving from [Angular Tree Component](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component) to the PrimeNg [Tree](https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/tree) component.
The tree selection is saved and restored when the application starts. We save the key field (folderId in our case).

[Angular Tree Component](https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component) exposes this method for finding the node:

```
const node = tree.treeModel.getNodeById(folderId);
```

After finding the node we can activate it by:

```
node.setActiveAndVisible();
```

I was unable to find a similar method for searching the node inside of the PrimeNg Tree. Does someone know what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

```
getNodeWithKey(key: string, nodes: TreeNode[]): TreeNode | undefined {
   for (let node of nodes) {
     if (node.key === key) {
        return node;
     }

     if (node.children) {
       let matchedNode = this.getNodeWithKey(key, node.children);
       if (matchedNode) {
         return matchedNode;
       }
     }
   }
   return undefined;
}
```

[used internally in primeng repository](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/0ec83bae617de2a7f25a18ffed1628aeaa79307e/src/app/components/tree/tree.ts#L993)